# What article started the Bitcoin bubble?

Tags: history, news-coverage

As I heard the Bitcoin bubble started around April 2011 due to an article on Bitcoin in some news website. What article started the Bitcoin bubble?

Comment: This question is speculative. Fun discussion, but not really answerable.

Comment: @lemonginger When asking this question I thought the answer would be more straightforward...

Comment: See also (not a duplicate): [Effect of media coverage on the exchange rate?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12125/4975)

Answer (score 3):

Press inquiries to me really picked up after [the Forbes article](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2011/0509/technology-psilocybin-bitcoins-gavin-andresen-crypto-currency.html) came out in the print edition of that magazine. I think that "mainstream press" mention started the publicity avalanche that fueled the bubble, although I'm a pattern-matching monkey like everybody else so take my opinion with a big grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

There were events that coincided with Bitcoin's rapid ascent, but not necessarily does that mean those events caused the bubble.

Jason Calacanis' "[Most dangerous open source project ever](http://www.launch.co/blog/l019-bitcoin-p2p-currency-the-most-dangerous-project-weve-ev.html)" post was one such time where the price spiked at the same time.

Jerry Brito's article raised some good attention and subsequent coverage in Forbes didn't hurt either.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Press#April

The real catalyst that got things started in Spring 2011 though was February's [Security Now podcast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCzsCmhkjMM) with Steve Gibson.

Comment: A question related to "where the price spiked at the same time": http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12125/4975

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was "[Underground Website Lets You Buy Any Drug Imaginable](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/06/silkroad/)" in [wired.com](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/06/silkroad/)'s "[Threat Level](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/)" on June 1, 2011 that triggered the bubble.  The bubble really started [just after that date](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#ig6-hourzczsg2011-05-25zeg2011-06-12ztgSzm1g10zm2g25).

Comment: That was also my impression. Not a positive spin, but certainly an engaging one.

Answer (score 1):

they started spamming Bitcoin-threads on 4chan's technology board. then the bitcoin prices started to rise. after the spike no one ever mentioned bitcoins again on 4chan. /job done/

personally i think they reached currency speculators  through 4chan (they also talk about finance, financing options and how much money they make through trading) and as a currency speculator, you know the weak spots of money.

Answer (score 0):

[A Slashdotting of BitcoinJ](http://news.slashdot.org/story/11/03/23/0210207/google-engineer-releases-open-source-bitcoin-client) is the first time that I personally saw Bitcoin mentioned anywhere ... and with a Google Engineer behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a big one that probably didnt start it, but fueled it and kept it going, http://falkvinge.net/2011/05/29/why-im-putting-all-my-savings-into-bitcoin/